# Replicating openssl commands using jsrsasign

Tags: javascript, openssl

I use the following set of openssl commands to generate client certificate

```
# create key
openssl genrsa -out client.key -aes256 -passout pass:password 2048

# create client certificate request 
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj '/C=UA/O=MyCompany/CN=MyName/emailAddress=test@example.com' -passin pass:password

# Sign client certificate request with intermediate CA private key
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA interm_cert.pem -CAkey interm_key.pem -CAcreateserial -CAserial intermediateCA.srl -extensions usr_cert -extfile openssl.conf -out client.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -passin pass:password

# generate client pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt -certfile interm_cert.pem

# convert to pem
openssl pkcs12 -in client.pfx -out client.pem -nodes
```

Now, I need to replicate that using jsrsasign library. Yes, I can easily create key pair using `KUTIL.generateKeypair` and certificate signing request, but this is as mach as I could figure out so far, using the library reference

Any help is greatly appreciated